# (#200) You do not have permission to create a scheduled post

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, facebook-graph-api

I can post fine a message but when i try to schedule the post I get that error, googling I found a similar issue on SO but with no answer. The documentation is not clear if I need other permision for scheduling or other access tocken, can someone please share a working example, and explain the list of permisions requiered and the type of access token?
Thanks

EDIT: I was posting to my profile page and that can't be done, thx Igy for your comment.
I created a page and again tried to post, without scheduling works but when scheduling I get now

> An unexpected error has occurred. Please retry your request later

.

```
private function publishToFacebook(dlg:PublishBlogDialog,date:Date):void{
            var mymessage:String=this.getTextNoTags();//this.htmlText;
            var page:Object=dlg.publishToFaceBook.table.source[dlg.publishToFaceBook.cmbPages.selectedIndex]
            var token:String=page.data.toString();
            var values:Object ;
            var ignoreScheduling:Boolean=false;
            if(ignoreScheduling){
                values= {message:mymessage,access_token:token};
            }
            else
            {
                var unixTime:int=date.time;
                values = {message:mymessage,access_token:token,published:false ,scheduled_publish_time:unixTime};
            }
            var method:String='/'+page.id+'/feed';
            FacebookDesktop.postData(method,handleUploadComplete,values);
        }
```

Comment: Please confirm you're using a page access token and posting to a page? I think if you incorrectly try to do this on a personal user account you get that message

Comment: @Igy thx, you are right, I updated my post with the new issue I have now

Answer (score -1):

You need to acquire the

> publish_stream

extended permission from the user and you can make posts at will using an app access token.

Comment: That's unlikely to have anything to do with the original question, the user says they can post regular messages correctly, it's only failing when they try to schedule a post